# C++ TCP server - recv returns

Tags: c++, tcp, server

I am creating a TCP server in C++ as a part of school assignment. This is how I send a message and then receive it.

```
string message_s = "100 LOGIN\r\n";
strcpy(senbuffer,message_s.c_str());
if(send(c, senbuffer, strlen(senbuffer), 0) < 0){
    perror("Cant send data!");
    close(c);
    return -3;
}
int bytesRead = recv(c, recbuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
if(bytesRead <= 0){
    perror("Socket read failed");
    close(c);
    exit;
}
```

The thing is - we have got a VirtualBox image for testing. But it just doesnt work on that image - recv returns 0. However when I try telnet it works like a charm. Does someone know what should I do next ? I will gladly post more code, but I didn't want to post the whole thing at beginning - it would make this page a mess.

Thank you very much

EDIT: this is where I get the c and the l from :

```
int l = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);    
int c = accept(l, (struct sockaddr *) &remote_address, &size);
```

Comment: Where did you get `c` from? What's at the other end of the socket?

Comment: The only thing that's wrong with the posted code is that it fails to handle the situation where fewer bytes were written by send(). send() does not guarantee that it will write the requested number of bytes. But for a short message like that, this is unlikely. So, there's nothing really wrong with the code you've shown, so your bug must be with the code that you have not shown here.

Comment: Please study the posting guidelines: You are supposed to first extract a minimal but complete example from your code. There are also reasons for that explained there.

Comment: @AlanStokes I have edited the post and added the c source. And what do you mean by the other end of socket ? Thats what we have the testing image from, it runs test to verify that the code meets the assignment requirements. But the catch is it doesnt work with the testing image but it works with telnet

Comment: recv() return 0 when remote peer closed it's connection. You should try to find why this happens. For example you send some wrong string, or did not send something it was expecting. I'd recommend logging somewhere everything you send and receive prior to the problem.